# Populating Next Right Pointers - Why Node.next is still null when passed recursively?

Tags: java, pointers, nullpointerexception, binary-search-tree

I am working on Leet code question [116. Populating Next Right Pointers in Each Node](https://leetcode.com/problems/populating-next-right-pointers-in-each-node/):

> You are given a **perfect binary tree** where all leaves are on the same level, and every parent has two children. The binary tree has the following definition:
>
> ```
> struct Node {
>   int val;
>   Node *left;
>   Node *right;
>   Node *next;
> }
> ```
>
> Populate each next pointer to point to its next right node. If there is no next right node, the next pointer should be set to `NULL`.
>
> Initially, all next pointers are set to `NULL`.

My solution is wrong. My question is about this piece of my code:

```
    if(root.right==null){
        return null;
    }
    root.left.next = root.right;

    root.right.next=null;
    connect(root.left);
    connect(root.right);

    return root;
```

I assign `root.right` to `root.left.next`, yet I find when `connect(root.left)` is passed, the `next` node is still `null`. How come there is still this `null`?

Comment: *I assign root.left.next to the root.right node,* - if you mean this: `root.left.next = root.right;` then it's assigning the root.right node to roor.left.next, the exact opposite of what you said.  Is this just a terminology problem or something more? `a = b`  means "assign b to a".

Comment: You are right, I described it wrong

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at the example tree:

[image]

Your code (i.e. the part you have shared) will establish all the red links, **except** the one between nodes 5 and 6, as those are not siblings! They are not the left/right children of the same `root` node. Or to describe that problem differently: your code will set the `next` property of **all** right-sided children to `null`. For nodes 3 and 7 that is the correct thing to do, but not for node 5. The higher the tree, the more nodes there are whose `next` property will not be set correctly.

So you'll need a different algorithm.

Hint: use a breadth-first traversal instead of the depth-first traversal that you have implemented.